# Nodejs async loop is blocking React UI render

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, asynchronous, electron

I have an electron application where I need to send a lot of data through UDP. This process is started through a click of a button in my React UI, and this example simplifies my problem. My React button:

```
<button
  onClick={() => {
    foo();
  }}
>
  Run foo
</button>;
```

Foo function:

```
export const foo = async () => {
  while (true) {
    console.log("hello");
  }
};
```

While foo is asynchronous, it still freezes the React UI!

Comment: JavaScript runs in a single thread. Even though the function is async, it will still block the application if you have it running an infinite while loop.

Comment: An async function is just a function that returns a promise. it says nothing about whether the thing you do in the function or inside the promise is async. You wrote a spinloop that will block the thread no matter where it's run.

Comment: An `async function`  (or promises in general) do not make things run in a different thread. To do that, you'll need to use a worker.

Comment: Yes @Bergi, I have been looking into using a workers as that would let me create a new thread, which would be my solution in any other language. Nodejs workers confuse me though... Not to say nodejs as a whole isn't confusing me

Comment: Can you share more details (and maybe code) about "*I need to send a lot of data through UDP*"? In general, the solution is to not do that in a synchronous `while(true)` loop, but to batch them in chunks, to intersperse them with delays, and/or to use the async OS capabilities to wait for the network buffer actually sending the packets.

Comment: @Bergi I am making a LAN stress tester, meaning I want to send all the data I can until I press the stop button.

Answer (score 3):

An `async` function still blocks the main (and only) thread while it's being executed; `async` functions help usually because they call library functions that actually free up the main thread.

For instance, if instead of doing a simple infinite loop you did something like this:

```
function timeout(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

function yieldThread() {
  return new Promise(resolve => resolve());
}

export const foo = async () => {
  while (true) {
    console.log("hello");
    await timeout(2000);
    //or
    await yieldThread();
  }
};
```

Your main thread wouldn't have been blocked.

Of course a `timeout` or a simple `yield` isn't usually the correct way to handle this situation, but it should exemplify the typical structure.

Assuming you have a function `sendUdp(packet, callback)` that has as first argument the packet
you need to send and as second a callback without arguments when it has finished sending,
you could do something like this:

```
export const foo = async () => {
  while (true) {
    const packet = getPacket();
    await new Promise(resolve => {
        sendUdp(packet, resolve);
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Trying your example, with `yieldThread`, still does freeze the UI.

Comment: @asd12tgzxvbgt is it completely frozen? For instance, if you try with the timeout example does it work? In that case, it's simply that you're firing a lot of requests and that's overloading the main thread, you should rate limit the requests. Note that in node the API supports sending multiple packets at the same time

Comment: Yup completely frozen. What's funny is that I created a function called `foo`, which logs console then calls `setTimeout(foo, 0);`. This worked for some time without freezing the UI. Then later on, I implemented my code to `foo`, and it froze again. I deleted more and more code to find the issue, but when I was back to the example that worked with `setTimeout(foo, 0)`, it still froze! Isn't that crazy?

Comment: @asd12tgzxvbgt Without having the code to try by hand, I would guess you are flooding the event loop; while it's true that you are not blocking the main thread technically, you are still spending almost all of your time in the `foo` function, and the UI freezes. You should add some delays; for instance, in your test, not `setTimeout(foo, 0)` but `setTimeout(foo, delay)` where `delay` is at least sometimes greater than 0

Answer (score 0):

Since JavaScript is single-threaded, as soon as your infinite while loop async function is called it will block your thread. You can get around this by introducing an `await` inside your while loop, which will allow your program to return to executing other parts of your code.

```
export const foo = async () => {
  while (true) {
    await new Promise(resolve => {
      resolve();
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Using your example definition of `foo` still does block the UI though.